# Client http socket em c

Tags: c

Galera gostaria que alguém me explicasse o seguinte trecho de código de um cliente http  faz, principalmente  essa expressão no `while(sent < strlen(get))`, o código completo se encontra [neste link](http://coding.debuntu.org/c-linux-socket-programming-tcp-simple-http-client).

```
 int sent = 0;

  while(sent < strlen(get))

  {

    tmpres = send(sock, get+sent, strlen(get)-sent, 0);

    if(tmpres == -1){

      perror("Can't send query");

      exit(1);
    }

    sent += tmpres;

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma chamada a `ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags)` envia **no máximo** `len` bytes do buffer apontado por `buf`. Pode ser que ele envie menos bytes que o máximo. Neste código, a variável `sent` conta o número de bytes que já foram enviados no socket; *enquanto* esse número for menor que o número total de bytes que precisam ser enviados, o laço continuará sendo executado.

Por exemplo, assumindo que a string `get` tenha 50 bytes. Na primeira iteração do laço (tratamento de erro removido), suponha que o socket envie apenas 30 bytes (em vez dos 50 que são pedidos):

```
while(sent < strlen(get))  // sent = 0, strlen(get) = 50
{
    // o terceiro parâmetro - strlen(get)-sent - é igual a 50
    tmpres = send(sock, get+sent, strlen(get)-sent, 0);
    // assumindo que o socket enviou 30 bytes, tempres = 30
    sent += tmpres; // sent = 30
}
```

Agora o terceiro parâmetro de `send` é igual a 20. Se nessa segunda chamada o socket enviar 20 bytes:

```
while(sent < strlen(get))  // sent = 30, strlen(get) = 50
{
    tmpres = send(sock, get+sent, strlen(get)-sent, 0);
    // assumindo que o socket enviou 20 bytes, tempres = 20
    sent += tmpres; // sent = 50
}
```

E com todos os bytes enviados, o laço termina.